# Option to push disabled in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have git integration set up with Visual Studio Code. I can commit just fine (so I think my credentials are set up correctly), and I can use `git push` from the command-line.

But, for some reason, `Sync`, `Pull`, and `Push` are all disabled (greyed out) in the Git section. What am I missing?

**Edit:** I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, if that matters.

Comment: Commit is a local operation and requires no credentials. I'd check to see if you have things setup as well as you thought you did. :-)

Comment: I see no settings in code to do this.  Are you talking about in git?

Comment: Can you verify that your branch is connected to a remote?

Comment: Also, please verify if the "Show Git Output" option provides some useful information?

Comment: @whoisj I added credentials and helpers I still don't see these options enabled. It must be something around that.

Comment: @Moriarty I re-opened my project (which has unstaged commits) and it's empty.

Comment: @BenjaminPasero it is, because I can push/pull from the terminal.

Comment: @ashes999 as I understand it, VS and VS Code do not use credential helpers. Instead, you must enter your credentials into the IDE itself.

Comment: @whoisj if you check [this VS Code git docs page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/versioncontrol), you'll see that `It's important that you set up a credential helper before you try out VS Code on a repository you cloned from an authenticated remote server. Credential management is not handled by VS Code for now.` Sad, but true.

Comment: I'm also having this issue, but on Windows. Looking into fixing it. I'll let you know if I figure it out first.

Comment: I have the same problem even on VSCode 0.5.0 which supports credentials management. I'm using GNU/Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Git version 1.7.9.5.

Answer (score 15):

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/my_branch
```

Or

```
git branch -u origin/my_branch
```

Comment: This worked for me the second option, we were able to pull push from command line but not from GUI, this helped a lot

Comment: this fixed my issue: git says commit created locally and then I got no pull/push/sync options. after running 'set-upstream-to' command this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue with Visual Studio 2022. Simply restarting Visual Studio solved it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Another soludtion could be renaming your remote repository to `origin`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/creatingrepo?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio#connect-a-local-repo-to-a-remote

Answer (score 1):

I simply clicked the bottom right branch menu, as the snapshot below, then click push.

[image]

Comment: question is about VS Code and not Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was starting Visual Studio with administrator rights

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, if that matters.

It, in fact, does!

I just had this problem today, and solved it only because I had it working in Windows, but broken on Linux, and the repos were setup identically.  Ubuntu's apt-get repos don't contain an up-to-date version of the git tools (it's a whole major version behind, wtf?).  My guess is they are using flags that differ between the versions when they are getting the remote repo information.

Here's what to do in Ubuntu to add an alternate repository that contains the latest versions of git, and install it:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install git
```

Restart VS Code, and all your git options are now properly enabled.

Comment: I would love to test and accept this answer. I have since moved on to Ubuntu 14.04. I'll test if the problem exists on 14.04 (12.04, IIRC, is no longer supported -- maybe that's why apt packages are far behind).